# Algebraic description of Gauss map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, grassmannians

Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ a smooth connected projective variety of
dimension $k$ over complex numbers. In classical literature
there is a Gauss map $\mathcal{G}: X \to \mathbb{G}(k, n)$ which
associates to every point $x$ of $X$ the projective tangent
plane $T_x X $. The smoothness assumption makes the map well defined.
We consider the composition of $\mathcal{G}$ with $k$-Pluecker
map embedding $\mathbb{G}(k, n)$ into certain projective space
$\mathbb{P}^N$. Let call this map $\widetilde{\mathbb{G}}: 
X \to \mathbb{P}^N$

Even thought I think the question arises rather naturally there is apparently a serious lack of literature discussing about algebraic description
of this map. It suggests that it's rather hard in general. Consider following "classical" situation:

Assume $X$ is defined by homogeneous polynomials $F_1,..., 
F_s$ each of degree $d$. Is it possible to express
$\widetilde{\mathbb{G}}$ as algebraic map of the form
$x \mapsto [G_0(x):...G_N(x)]$ for appropriate polynomials
depending on $F_1,..., F_s$?

There is a simple special case: assume $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$
is smooth hyperplane defined by polynomial $F$. Then the Gauss map
$\widetilde{\mathbb{G}}: 
X \to \mathbb{G}(n-1, n)= \mathbb{P}^{n \ *}$ is described by
$x \mapsto [\frac{\partial F(x)}{\partial X_0}:...:
\frac{\partial F(x)}{\partial X_n}]$.

The question is if we can write down a generalization to
subvariety $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ described
by several $F_1,..., F_s$?

Comment: Yes, sure, just take minors of the matrix $(\partial F_i / \partial X_j)$ of appropriate size.